# Не знаю, как правильно вызвать ошибку вместе со своим сообщением

Tags: python, python-3.x, шаблоны-проектирования

Не знаю, как правильно вызвать ошибку вместе со своим сообщением. Еще не очень понимаю, почему следующий вызов функции не сработал, пожалуйста, помогите! Задание по которому я писал:

> Написать функцию email_parse(<email_address>), которая при помощи
> регулярного выражения извлекает имя пользователя и почтовый домен из
> email адреса и возвращает их в виде словаря. Если адрес не валиден,
> выбросить исключение ValueError. Пример:

```
>>> email_parse('someone@geekbrains.ru')
{'username': 'someone', 'domain': 'geekbrains.ru'}
>>> email_parse('someone@geekbrainsru')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: wrong email: someone@geekbrainsru
```

Вот мой код:

```
import re
list_email = []
dict_info = {}
def email_parse(email_address):
    try:
        if email_address != ''.join((re.findall(r"\w+[@]\w+[/.]\w+", email_address))):
            raise ValueError()

    except ValueError:
        msg = 'wrong email {}'.format(str(email_address))
        raise ValueError(msg)

    else:
        val_1 = re.findall(r"\w+", email_address)
        val_2 = val_1[0]
        val_3 = re.findall(r'@\w+[/.]\w+', email_address)
        dict_info['username'] = val_2
        dict_info["domain"] = ''.join(val_3)


    return dict_info
print(email_parse('!!!!!f@gma'))
print(email_parse('shop24@gmail.com'))
```

Вот что в вышло:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/79309/Desktop/ПРОЕКТЫ/Август_Фавн_dz_8/project_1/main.py",
> line 7, in email_parse
> raise ValueError() ValueError
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/79309/Desktop/ПРОЕКТЫ/Август_Фавн_dz_8/project_1/main.py",
> line 22, in 
> print(email_parse('!!!!!f@gma'))   File "C:/Users/79309/Desktop/ПРОЕКТЫ/Август_Фавн_dz_8/project_1/main.py",
> line 11, in email_parse
> raise ValueError(msg) ValueError: wrong email !!!!!f@gma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def email_parse(email_address):
    parsed = re.findall(r"([^@&]+)@([\w_-][\w_\.-]*\.[\w_-]{2,})$", email_address)
    if not parsed:
        raise ValueError(f"wrong email: {email_address}")
    return dict(zip(["username", "domain"], parsed[0]))
```

тесты:

```
In [190]: email_parse("someone@geekbrains.ru")
Out[190]: {'username': 'someone', 'domain': 'geekbrains.ru'}

In [191]: email_parse("someone@geekbrainsru")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
skipped
...
ValueError: wrong email: someone@geekbrainsru
```

Comment: Да, но если я запущу сначала заведомо не правильный емейл, то если запущу потом с новым, нормальным, у меня проигнорируется, так как программа приостановлена из-за ошибки

Comment: @Август, этого требует условие задачи! Неперехваченные/необработанные исключения завершают работу Python скрипта

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Только вопрос не по теме, а почему и как работает такая короткая версия как: if not parsed? То есть, это же буквально Если не (и тут регулярка), но не очень понимаю, если не, то что? В общем, как оно работает:::))

Comment: @Август, `if not parsed` - проверяет является ли список `parsed` пустым или переменная == `None` - в этом случае выбрасываем исключение. Если условие не выполнилось программа выполняется дальше

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

можно и проще чем

```
re.findall(r"([^@&]+)@([\w_-][\w_\.-]*\.[\w_-]{2,})$" email_address)
```

вот так например

```
re.findall(r'(^\w+)@((\w+).(\w{2,}))$
```